# Attach Events to User Permissions in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010

I know you can create events in SharePoint for custom lists, sites, and etc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff728093.aspx.  Unfortunately, they don't trigger within the permissions section of SharePoint.

I'm trying to find a way to capture the events in the permissions section.  For example, I want to know when a user or group has been added to a site collection.  Does anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

There are some clunky ways:

1. Use a custom page to manage permissions instead (doesn't cater for stsadm.exe / Powershell / other "non-UI techniques)
2. Use a timer job to repeatedly check permissions and compare against previous settings
3. Use a HTTPModule to somehow intercept the postback (doesn't cater for stsadm.exe etc.)

Comment: I might have to end up using the timer because I don't have access to the server.